Indexability of Restless Multi-Armed Bandit Problem
While reading a book on Restless multi-armed bandit problem (specifically Ch.6 of J.C. Gittins, 2011: Multi‐Armed Bandit Allocation Indices), the idea of indexability comes up yet I find it hard to process.
Suppose we have a discrete tome stochastic process $X_t \in \Omega$ where at each state $x_t$ we get to choose 2 actions:

Active mode $(A)$, which yields some immediate reward of $r_A$ 
Passive mode $(P)$, which yields some immediate reward of $r_P$

Also, the stochastic process will evolve according to actions, i.e. the next state either follows $P_A(\cdot|x_t)$ or $P_P(\cdot|x_t)$ according to the action. The Whittle index to solve such restless arm bandit problem for a state, denoted by $W(x_t)$, is to find the minimum passive reward, $r_P^*$ such that we are indifferent in choosing active or passive action at state $x_t$.
The indexability notion is defined as: for two passive rewards, $r_{p1}, r_{p2}$ if $r_{p1} > r_{p2}$ then set of states where passive action is optimal when the passive rewards is $r_{p2}$ is a subset of the set of states where passive action is optimal when the passive rewards is $r_{p1}$.
However, the book says not all problem are indexable, i.e. not all stochastic processes has the above monotonic relationship---increase of the passive rewards leads to more states choosing passive action as optimal action.  I tried to construct stochastic process that is not indexable, however, I have not find any.
Please enlight me with a stochastic process that is not indexable, thanks!

If the transition probabilities remain the same, and you increase the passive reward from $r_{p_2}$ to $r_{p_1}$ then in any state it was optimal to choose passive under $r_{p_2}$ it must still be optimal to choose passive under $r_{p_1}$ (dynamics are the same, and we receive greater immediate reward). I assume then we are also allowed to change the transition probabilities?

@msantama  The transition probabilities for a state is only different when the action chosen at the state is different. If we are choosing passive action, then the transition probabilities for a given state should be the same. However, if the passive reward changes, the optimal action at some state could change, which will lead to transition probabilities changes.

Are the rewards state dependent?

@msantama Yes! Something I want to clarify is that the passive reward, however, is not state dependent.
